# JSON data 400 Bad request Error

Tags: javascript, sql, json

I have JSON data sending to server. When I submit the for it is printing the data in console but not sending to the server.

It gives the following error

```
POST http://localhost:8080/rest/review/createReview 400 (Bad Request)
```

Here is my code

```
var promise = jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/review/createReview',
      type: 'POST',
      data: '{myReview: myReview}',
      dataType: "text",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (data) {
           console.log("Request successful", data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
          console.log("Request failed", data); 
      }
    });
```

Comment: What are you posting it to? If it is something like ASP.Net MVC 4 then it might be routing that is off.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: '{ "myReview": myReview}' ???

Comment: Shouldn't it be: '{ "myReview": myReview}' ???

Comment: Shouldn't it be: '{ "myReview": myReview}' ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that your data is not valid JSON. Try:

```
data: JSON.stringify({myReview: myReview})
```

Comment: Hey Thanks  it is adding row in db but myReview column shows null there. why?

Comment: @Sowmya I don't know.  What value is being passed by javascript?